# Show APP_KEY in Laravel debug mode

Tags: php, laravel, debug-mode, cve

I'm trying to build a vulnerable Laravel webserver to exploit the CVE-2018-15133.

To exploit this vulnerability, the webserver needs to print out the APP_KEY in the debug view of laravel. I've installed Laravel 5.5.40, which is vulnerable, and I was able to turn on the debug mode. My problem is that I cannot show the debug key inside the debug view of laravel.

[image: error view]

If I try to print the `$_ENV` variable inside the controller, it prints out an empty array, while if I print out `env('APP_KEY')`, it can reach this value.

My goal is to achieve this debug view.
[image]

This picture is taken from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEBZxDV6k6M&ab_channel=DoctorDNATYPING).

Comment: Could you create a github repo of your code and share it?

Comment: Of course, here It is: [link](https://github.com/matteosantini/laravel-vuln-5). In order to check the debug view just run the "php artisan serv" and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/.